# Calculate combinations in java

Tags: java, combinatorics

I'm trying to write an algorithm in Java to calculate the optimum order of batsmen in a cricket game, based on the experience they have playing in each order.

I have a list of 11 lists. 
Each of the 11 lists contains all 11 batsmen in the team, ranked by the number of games they've played in this position.

So the first list would start with the player who's played most games in the first position, and ends with the player who's played least games in first position. The second list starts with the player who's played most games in 2nd position, and ends with the player who's played least games in 2nd position. etc..

What I want to do is find the combination of batsmen, one from each list, which minimises the sum of the players' locations in the lists. If all players have only played one game then this would be easy, the top player of each list. However some players top more than one list, while others may not top any.

I realise this may need quite a few loops, what is the most efficient way to calculate this?
If you need any more info please ask..sorry it's a bit confusing...

Is this going to be 11! combinations? Oh gaaaaad

Comment: Is this one team 11 lists?

Comment: it's good, what did you try?

Comment: Do the lists contain only the ordering of the players, or also the number of played games at each position per player?

Comment: @Roman C I'm still thinking about it, I think the easiest way is to go through the first list, take the top player, then remove that player from the other lists, then repeat with the second list all the way down. Then start again with the second most experienced player in the first list. etc.. looping every combination,  then keeping a record of the sum of all combinations - I'm just worried it's going to take ages.

Comment: @aksappy one team, 11 lists (one for each position in the batting line up)

Comment: @tobias_k It contains the number of games as well, along with a fair few other bits of information. Each list element is an object[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Guava method [Collections2.permutations](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#permutations%28java.util.Collection%29)  calculates for you all the possible permutations (11!), does all the looping, you only need to evaluate the results.

EDIT: in order to check the memory consumption, run the following test (it takes some time, but you shouldn't get an OutOfMemoryError):

```
public class Perm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11");
        Collection<List<String>> permutations = Collections2.permutations(list);
        for (List<String> strings : permutations) {
            String s = strings.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this going to require an insane amount of storage?

Comment: @ed Bevan: no, the returned PermutationCollection has a PermutationIterator which calculates the results on the fly as you iterate it (check out the source code)

Comment: Ah that's pretty decent then. Cheers!